# Exporting Vagrant boxes from Linux to Windows

Tags: vagrant

I'm using Windows as my main OS and Linux through Virtualbox for development. I would like to learn Vagrant and create a Linux box using it. After my new box is created using Vagrant, can I somehow export it to Windows so that I can use it without Vagrant? I mean can I start it straight from Windows' Virtualbox?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Vagrant on Windows?

Comment: Googling "Vagrant on Windows"...